# Can webparts in sharepoint online access external data securely?

Tags: authentication, sharepoint-online, web-parts

We are using sharepoint on-premise with webparts to display charts on
sharepoint pages. The webparts are part of a third party solution.
I believe the webparts use the "web proxy in SharePoint" feature to access
an on-premise server which is part of the solution.

Now we have to migrate to sharepoint online. The third party says it is trying to port the software to Sharepint online. Of course they are very late.

So I am wondering if porting is possible at all.

I believe the problem is that the webparts in Sharepoint online are client only.
These web parts have to access another server for data. This would be a
cross domain call. And how would authentication work?

When I search the sharepoint documentation I always encounter
" Important

The SharePoint Add-In model in SharePoint Online has been retired as of November 27th 2023, checkout the full retirement announcement to learn more.
"

So is it possible to have webparts in Sharepoint online that access external data in a secure way (authenticated)?